# What to use instead of getSupportActionBar() in Library 22?

Tags: android, toolbar, appcompatactivity

There is a line in my code, that marked as yellow:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

After installing *appcompat-v7:22.1*  it shows a hint:

> "Method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception".

What should be used instead of `getSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: Check for nulls first to avoid the warning.

Comment: Make sure you are extending `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Should say

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

getSupportActionBar() can return null so you the hint is telling you about this.

Answer (score 2):

I found another way, using *AppCompatDelegate*:

```
        getDelegate().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending a `Theme.AppCompat` which has an action bar or have called `setSupportActionBar(...)` yourself, calling `getSupportActionBar()` is safe.

To get around the warning do a null check or

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
```

which will throw an exception if the expression is not true. Both have their uses.

Answer (score 1):

Are using `NoActionBar` in styles? Verify your `style.xml` or you theme, `if("NoActionBar") => nullpointer =D`