# NPE at getSupportActionBar() on OnePlus One Running Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My user who's using OnePlus One (A0001) running Android 5.1 reported this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBar android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar()' on a null object reference
    at com.imincode.meniti.MenuHome.onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuHome.java:558)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:2044)
```

Line 558 in my code is:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Apparently he's the only one with this problem. Other devices never encountered such error. How do I fix this?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899311/what-to-use-instead-of-getsupportactionbar-in-library-22) suggests we use

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

but then how would the actionBar behaves on devices that returns null? How do we set setDisplayShowTitleEnabled and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled on such devices?

In my OnCreateView, I have this line:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); 
if (toolbar != null) {
   ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Btw here's the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBar android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar()' on a null object reference
    at com.imincode.meniti.MenuHome.onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuHome.java:558)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:2044)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2063)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentController.java:270)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:263)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
    at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5278)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:375)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you are using a `theme` that has no ActionBar, while you are not using `ToolBar` as well.

If you want to use ActionBar, check your `theme`

If you are using ToolBar, you have to call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` before calling `getSupportActionBar()`

**Edit:**

According to your edit, your Toolbar is inside layout of `Fragment`,

To solve your problem, use one of these methods:

1. Move your `toolbar` to layout of `Activity` and call `setSupportActionBar` in `onCreate` of `Activity`; Or
2. Do not use `setSupportActionBar` or `getSupportActionBar` or anything related to `ActionBar`, use `Toolbar` as Toolbar, e.g. call `toolbar.inflateMenu` to inflate menu

**Edit 2**

Looking at your stack trace,

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBar android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar()' on a null object reference`

It is caused by `getActivity()` returning null.

Seems you are trying to call `getActivity()` in `Fragment#onCreateOptionMenu`, you should not try to access `Activity` in the method.

Move those methods really need `Activity` to `onActivityCreated` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd try the methods that you suggest, but since I don't have OnePlus One on hand, it would be very difficult for me to test whether the solution works or not. But why do this error only appear in OnePlus One, and not other phones?

Comment: I believe it depends on the order `onCreateView` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` is resolved, which has no clear defined order

Comment: Although I love Android, this kind of issues really put me off.

Comment: O, I am sorry, after looking into more details from stack trace, the cause of your problem is not that, though it could still be a problem. It is `getActivity` returning `null`, can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've added the full stack trace. And yes, MenuHome is a fragment.

Comment: No, problem, I think my 2nd edit is valid, you should only inflate menu in `onCreateOptionMenu`, and not include command which requires reference to `Activity`